# SuperNotCalledExeption onPause()

Tags: fragment, onpause

I am using this example: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html but in a fragment and I am getting a SuperNotCalledException for onPause() I used the debugger and it is failing when adding the images to the linear view not really sure why though if someone could help me I will greatly appreciate it :

File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

```
    for (File file : files){
     myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using something based on the [call super](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super) antipattern.  Is your `onPause()` method required to call the superclass implementation (e.g. with `super(args)`)?

Comment: I really don't know much about the Lifecycle, I am still confused I don't even have a onPause() in my code, just an onCreate()

Comment: OK.  Is your `onCreate()` method required to call the superclass?

Comment: Yes, I am calling the superclass

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `super.onPause()` in your `onPause()` method.